# Mutate across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to recode values in the fruit2 and fruit3 columns without having to write out the recode function for each column.

```
fruit1<-c("Apples","Oranges","Apples","Grapes","Apples","Oranges")
fruit2<-c("Apples","Oranges","Apples","Grapes","Apples","Oranges")
fruit3<-c("Apples","Oranges","Apples","Grapes","Apples","Oranges")
data<-data.frame(fruit1,fruit2,fruit3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)%>%
  mutate(fruit2=recode(fruit2, Apples="Apple"),
        fruit3=recode(fruit2, Apples="Apple"),             
                       )
```

I understand you can use the across verb to do things across columns but I cant get it to work. I have so far:

```
data<-data.frame(fruit1,fruit2,fruit3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)%>%
  mutate(across(c(fruit2,fruit3)),recode(Apples="Apple"))
```

Can anyone suggest any edits to the code to make it work?

Comment: What is fruit1?

Comment: It is there now, initial code error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
fruit1<-c("Apples","Oranges","Apples","Grapes","Apples","Oranges")
fruit2<-c("Apples","Oranges","Apples","Grapes","Apples","Oranges")
fruit3<-c("Apples","Oranges","Apples","Grapes","Apples","Oranges")
data<-data.frame(fruit1,fruit2,fruit3, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data %>%
  mutate(across(c(fruit2, fruit3), ~ recode(.x, Apples="Apple")))
#>    fruit1  fruit2  fruit3
#> 1  Apples   Apple   Apple
#> 2 Oranges Oranges Oranges
#> 3  Apples   Apple   Apple
#> 4  Grapes  Grapes  Grapes
#> 5  Apples   Apple   Apple
#> 6 Oranges Oranges Oranges
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `replace`

```
data %>% mutate(across(2:3, ~  replace(., . == 'Apples','Apple')))
   fruit1  fruit2  fruit3
1  Apples   Apple   Apple
2 Oranges Oranges Oranges
3  Apples   Apple   Apple
4  Grapes  Grapes  Grapes
5  Apples   Apple   Apple
6 Oranges Oranges Oranges
```